# Creating a series of Quarters from pandas PeriodIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have below `pandas` array of quarters

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.PeriodIndex(year=[2000, 2002], quarter=[1, 3]) # ['2000Q1', '2002Q3']
```

Now I want to create a continuous array of 100 subsequent quarters starting from `2002Q3` above. Is there any method/function available to achieve this?

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: Would the actual dates of the EOQ work for you?  `pd.date_range('2002Q3', periods=100, freq='Q')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.period_range('2002Q3', periods=100, freq='Q')
```

Output:

```
PeriodIndex(['2002Q3', '2002Q4', '2003Q1', '2003Q2', '2003Q3', '2003Q4',
             '2004Q1', '2004Q2', '2004Q3', '2004Q4', '2005Q1', '2005Q2',
             '2005Q3', '2005Q4', '2006Q1', '2006Q2', '2006Q3', '2006Q4',
             '2007Q1', '2007Q2', '2007Q3', '2007Q4', '2008Q1', '2008Q2',
             '2008Q3', '2008Q4', '2009Q1', '2009Q2', '2009Q3', '2009Q4',
             '2010Q1', '2010Q2', '2010Q3', '2010Q4', '2011Q1', '2011Q2',
             '2011Q3', '2011Q4', '2012Q1', '2012Q2', '2012Q3', '2012Q4',
             '2013Q1', '2013Q2', '2013Q3', '2013Q4', '2014Q1', '2014Q2',
             '2014Q3', '2014Q4', '2015Q1', '2015Q2', '2015Q3', '2015Q4',
             '2016Q1', '2016Q2', '2016Q3', '2016Q4', '2017Q1', '2017Q2',
             '2017Q3', '2017Q4', '2018Q1', '2018Q2', '2018Q3', '2018Q4',
             '2019Q1', '2019Q2', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2020Q2',
             '2020Q3', '2020Q4', '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2021Q4',
             '2022Q1', '2022Q2', '2022Q3', '2022Q4', '2023Q1', '2023Q2',
             '2023Q3', '2023Q4', '2024Q1', '2024Q2', '2024Q3', '2024Q4',
             '2025Q1', '2025Q2', '2025Q3', '2025Q4', '2026Q1', '2026Q2',
             '2026Q3', '2026Q4', '2027Q1', '2027Q2'],
            dtype='period[Q-DEC]')
```